# How to write the curl command to imitate get method?

Tags: php, http, curl, get

```
cd /var/www/html/phplearn
```

For the http post request and response.

vim send_local_post.php

```
<form action=http://127.0.0.1/phplearn/do_post.php method=post>
user:  <input type=text name=userName size=12/>
key:    <input type=text name=PS size=12/>
<input type=submit value=login>
</form>
```

vim  do_post.php

```
<?php
$userName = $_POST["userName"];
$PS = $_POST["PS"];
echo "the name is:  ".$userName."\n";
echo "key word is:  ".$PS."\n";
?>
```

Let's imitate post method with curl in console.

```
curl -X POST -d "userName=user&PS=key"  127.0.0.1/phplearn/do_post.php
```

The output in console is as below:

[image]

For the http get request and response.

vim send_local.get.php

```
<form action=http://127.0.0.1/phplearn/do_get.php method=get>
user:  <input type=text name=userName size=12/>
key:   <input type=text name=PS size=12/>
<input type=submit value=login>
</form>
```

vim  do_get.php

```
<?php
$userName = $_GET["userName"];
$PS = $_GET["PS"];
echo "the name is:  ".$userName."\n";
echo "key word is:  ".$PS."\n";
?>
```

Let's imitate get method with curl in console.

```
curl  http://127.0.0.1/phplearn/do_get.php?userName=user&PS=key
```

The output in console is as below:
[image]

Why the key value can't displayed on the console such as post method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the ampersand. When bash hits the ampersand it triggers a background process, and cuts off the remaining text.

This is also why you see `[1] 14975` because it's spinning off a new process, and running it in the background.

To fix this, simply enclose your url in quotes:

```
curl "http://127.0.0.1/phplearn/do_get.php?userName=user&PS=key"
```